# How to Add Permission on Visual Basic for Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-10

I'm creating a simple timer software for windows 10 desktop, as the app start i want to disable task manager, cmd, and registry..

Currently on disabling task manager using the following code

```
Dim regkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
Dim keyValueInt As String = "1"
Dim subKey As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
Try
   regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(subkey:=subKey)
   regkey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", keyValueInt)
   regkey.Close()
Catch

End Try
```

I'm receiving..

> Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll

I'm using the Visual Studio 2017 Community in windows 10.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't C# and editing the registry requires elevation.

Comment: updated the tags, thanks for the info, looking in "elevation" right now

Comment: that solved the things, this is my first vb app so im quite not sure about things, thanks for the help guys